# Notification not getting cleared after a few seconds. -Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

**SOLVED, thanks to everyone that contributed.**

This is my function that I use to display the notification to the user. However, for some reason, it looks like the notifications are not getting deleted anymore... not sure why. Note the variable NOTIFICATION is initialized as:

```
public static  int NOTIFICATION = 1;  
public void displayNotification(String title, String message, Intent intent) {
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtx, NOTIFICATION, 
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //FLAG_ONE_SHOT ? FLAG_UPDATE_CURRRENT

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mCtx);
    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo_nobg).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo_nobg)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mCtx.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_roundedlogo))
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .build();

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mCtx
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);

    // This method will get rid of the notification AND the message after 1 day
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION);
                    Preference_Manager.getInstance(mCtx).deleteKeyMessage(NOTIFICATION);
                    // Preference_Manager.getInstance(mCtx).deleteKeyMessageid(NOTIFICATION);
                }
            }, 5000/*howMany */);

        }
    });
    NOTIFICATION++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe check this also

```
public static  int NOTIFICATION = 1;  


public void displayNotification(String title, String message, Intent intent) {
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtx, NOTIFICATION, 
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //FLAG_ONE_SHOT ? FLAG_UPDATE_CURRRENT

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mCtx);
    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo_nobg).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo_nobg)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mCtx.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_roundedlogo))
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .build();

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mCtx
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);

    final int notificationId = NOTIFICATION;

    // This method will get rid of the notification AND the message after 1 day
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
                    Preference_Manager.getInstance(mCtx).deleteKeyMessage(notificationId);
                    // Preference_Manager.getInstance(mCtx).deleteKeyMessageid(NOTIFICATION);
                }
            }, 5000/*howMany */);

        }
    });
    NOTIFICATION++;
}
```

Comment: See I'm using local final variable for notification id

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `run()` method did not get called.
Use this code directly

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION);
        Preference_Manager.getInstance(mCtx).deleteKeyMessage(NOTIFICATION);
        // Preference_Manager.getInstance(mCtx).deleteKeyMessageid(NOTIFICATION);
    }
}, 5000/*howMany */);
```

insted of calling it into another `Runnable` that is never get called.

For clear all notification use this method:

```
public void clearNotifications(Context context) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
}
```

Hope it help you..

Comment: Sent 2 notifications, only deleted 1

Comment: are you using same key in both notification i.e. NOTIFICATION =1??

Comment: As you can see at the end of the code, notification gets incremented at the end of the function

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use the cancelAll() method because, the 'howmany' variable is the amount of time in which notification should be deleted, which changes depending of the notification, but I truly appreciate the input.

Comment: We have to pass the same id to in cancel(id) method that you are using in notify() method,, but in your case it is incremented , you have to keep it somewhere to cancel.

Answer (score 0):

It will not remove notification as your NOTIFICATION Value is incremented and in Runnable of post delayed it will check for updated value.

Try to use `notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION - 1);` 
It should work

You can store last deleted value in one variable NOTIFICATION_DELETED and in your handler,

```
for(int i = NOTIFICATION_DELETED ;i < NOTIFICATION;i++){ 
    notificationManager.cancel(i); 
}
```

Comment: it worked, but if I send 2 notifications, it will only delete the first one

Comment: There are two options to clear notifications, Either you can clear all notification using notificationManager.cancelAll(), or you have to use the loop to clear all notification one by one.

Comment: The thing is that I do not want to delete all of them, only that specific one, since the times for delete will be different, should I be using a different method than a handler?